# getting return values from nested functions

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, google-visualization, html5-filesystem

Newbie to scripting so please be kind.
Attempting to create chart from local file using jquery-csv parser. using google viz.
this section of code i cant seem to get a return value from. 
Require the return value of the parsed file selected.

Is it better to use callback? and how would i implement that? have tried but cant seem to get it right.

```
 function chartData(fileToParse) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(fileToParse);
reader.onload = function(){
  var csv = event.target.result;
 var parsedData = $.csv.toArrays(csv,{onParseValue:$.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
 return parsedData
};
return reader.onload.value;

reader.onerror = function(){ alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName); };
```

}

i have already used this code modified to show data in table form on screen but have hit  a wall with getting it to the google servers.

Any advice or pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your intended result with the line that reads `return reader.onload.value;` ? Are you hoping that the chartData function returns the value that is loaded by reader's onload method?

Comment: I require (i think) the parsed data from the csv so i can use 'arraytoDataTable'. see below. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Is it better to use callback?"*

Yes, this would be the proper solution

> *"and how would i implement that?"*

1. Define a second argument for your `chartData` function.
2. When you invoke `chartData`, pass a callback as the second argument.
3. Inside the event handlers, invoke the callback in the same way you'd invoke any function, but pass the desired data to it.

---

```
                   // receive it-----v
 function chartData(fileToParse, callback) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsText(fileToParse);
     reader.onload = function () {
         var csv = event.target.result;
         var parsedData = $.csv.toArrays(csv, {
             onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar
         });
         callback(parsedData); // call it
     };

     reader.onerror = function () {
         alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName);
     };
 }
```

And so you'd invoke it like this:

```
chartData('file/path', function(parsed) {
    console.log(parsed);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt replies.

Comment: oops. wrong key. Just tried that and have thrown up 'not an array'. looking at code again. I am thinking i have missed out something.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help. The above code worked, but it appears most of my other attempts worked in some kind of way, and it is the jquery-csv which is causing the problems.parsing the code nicely but google not understanding it. looking further into it.

Comment: conclusion: something happens to file when converted from csv, or when pushed to arrayToDataTable. array created in code looks exactly same as array imported from file, but google wont accept it. will have to create my own table from imported data with addrow etc.

Comment: my coding error actually. not understanding value passing enough. thanks to asgallant on google visualization group for showing me the error.

Comment: full file on http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/edT7T/7/. select local file and create graph from it.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem with a similar problem with async functions.

Answer (score 0):

First off, please don't ask us to be kind as that is an "unkind" assumption on your part

Generally, you can't return a value from an asynchronous function.  You should consider why you want to return a value and see if you can look at it from another angle.  For example, what do you need to do with the parsedData.. populate a textarea?, attach some elements to the Dom?.. then do it right there!

Let us know what you need from the parsedData and we can assist.

Lastly, in desperation you can attach the response to a global object such as window but that will create a host of other issues

Comment: my apologies for the 'kind' comment. It was meant in good taste.

Comment: oops. must stop pressing return. Value is to be sent to google charts, but i have just adjusted code and it returns 'not a valid 2D array'. am going to look further into how array is constructed and compare to other google viz code. Thank you all for oyur help so far.